# Trying to create 5 tags in a many to many relation with prisma, but getting error

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to create a question that has 4 answers and 5 tags, but when I try to create multiple tags, I get this error: Type '{ create: { nome: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'never', but when I create only one tag it works just fine. I'm using NestJS and Prisma.

**This gives me the error: Type '{ create: { nome: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'never'**

```
const savedQuestion = await this.prisma.question.create({
        data: {
          tema: createQuestionDto.tema,
          questao: createQuestionDto.questao,
          nivel: createQuestionDto.nivel,
          answer: {
            create: [
              {texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto},
              {texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto},
              {texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto},
              {texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto},
            ],
          },
          question_tags: {
            create: {
              tags: {
                create: [
                  {nome: "test"},
                  {nome: "test"},
                  {nome: "test"},
                  {nome: "test"},
                  {nome: "test"},
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
```

**This works fine, but only creates one tag**

```
const savedQuestion = await this.prisma.question.create({
        data: {
          tema: createQuestionDto.tema,
          questao: createQuestionDto.questao,
          nivel: createQuestionDto.nivel,
          answer: {
            create: [
              {texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto},
              {texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto},
              {texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto},
              {texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto},
            ],
          },
          question_tags: {
            create: {
              tags: {
                create: {nome: "test"},      
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
```

**My postgre tables**

```
create table QUESTION (
    id serial primary key,
    tema varchar(255) not null,
    questao text not null,
    NIVEL NIVEL not null
);

create table TAGS(
    id serial primary key,
    nome varchar(255) not null
);

create table QUESTION_TAGS(
    question_id int not null references question(id),
    tags_id int not null references tags(id),
    primary key (question_id, tags_id)
);


create table ANSWER(
    id serial primary key,
    texto text not null,
    question_id int not null references question(id)
);

CREATE TYPE NIVEL AS ENUM ('facil', 'medio', 'dificil', 'muito dificil', 'expert');
```

**Prisma Schema**

```
model quetion{
  id            Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  tema          String          @db.VarChar(255)
  questao       String
  nivel         nivel
  question_tags question_tags[]
  answer        answer[]
}

model answer{
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  texto       String
  question_id Int
  question    question @relation(fields: [question_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
}

model tags {
  id            Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  nome          String          @db.VarChar(255)
  question_tags question_tags[]
}

model question_tags {
  question_id Int
  tags_id     Int
  question    question @relation(fields: [question_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  tags        tags     @relation(fields: [tags_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)

  @@id([question_id, tags_id], map: "Pergunta_Tags_pk")
}
```

Comment: Many to many relationships in Prisma have to be explicitly defined in the Prisma schema for it to work. You have to create a bridge table. https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations

Comment: @SadequsHaque I have added my prisma schema, I'm doing it in a explicity way

Comment: Can you share the schema for answer_tags? Its used in model questions.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it should be question_tags, I'm actually doing it in portuguese, so when I have to put it here I need to translate it.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to realize what the snippet of code is doing. Your code is unnecessarily complicated.  Let's break down what its doing step by step.

1. It is creating a question with one `question_tags`.
2. As per the schema, one `question_tags` can have one `tags`.
3. In the first snippet, you are creating **five** `tags` and assigning them to the **one** `question_tags` (A `question_tags` can only have **one** `tags`), and so you are getting a type error.
4. The second snippet fixes the type error by only assigning **one** `tags` to the `question_tags`.

Now, you want to have five `question_tags` each of which has an individual `tags`. To do that, you want multiple `create` objects in the `question_tags[]` array. It would look something like this (add more `create` objects in the array).

```
const savedQuestion = await this.prisma.question.create({
  data: {
    tema: createQuestionDto.tema,
    questao: createQuestionDto.questao,
    nivel: createQuestionDto.nivel,
    answer: {
      create: [
        { texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto },
        { texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto },
        { texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto },
        { texto: createQuestionDto.answer[0].texto },
      ],
    },
    question_tags: [
        
        //The first question_tags gets created because of this block of code
      {
        create: {
          tags: {
            create: { nome: "test" },
          },
        },
      },

        //The second question_tags get created because of this block of code
      {
        create: {
          tags: {
            create: { nome: "test" },
          },
        },
      },
      
    ],
    
  },
});
```

A few more things I wanted to mention:

1. Try to name variables in English and as descriptively as possible. Proper variable naming is one of the easiest things to do that makes your code "cleaner".
2. You probably do not want to design your database like this. I would use `tags` + `enums` or `question_tags` + `enums`. I would not have `question_tags` reference `tags`. It makes the code much harder to understand.

Comment: question_tags is a many to many relation, there is a better way to write it? I'm new at creating databases, what do you mean by question_tags + enums? like create multiple enums for example Java, JS, Python, etc, if so, would't it make the code more verbose? Also thank you for your help.